# Url rewriting in web filter

Tags: servlets, servlet-filters, requestdispatcher

In my JSF application, I would like to implement a web filter to change the requested view in function of the used device (I use spring-mobile device resolver).

I have this in my filter:

```
    String requestURI = request.getRequestURI();

    Device device = DeviceUtils.getCurrentDevice(request);

    if (!requestURI.contains("/mobile") && device.isMobile()) {
        String newUri = requestURI.replace("/contextroot/faces/html/", "/contextroot/faces/html/mobile/");
        request.getRequestDispatcher(newUri).forward(request, response);
    }
    else {
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

But I get an exception

```
/contextroot/faces/html/mobile/consult/consult.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it works with requestURI.replace("/contextroot/faces/html/", "/faces/html/mobile/");

Answer (score 0):

The [`HttpServletRequest#getRequestDispatcher()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) takes a path relative to the context root, so you shouldn't include the path of the context root itself. This is clearly specified in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getRequestDispatcher%28java.lang.String%29) (emphasis mine):

> ...
>
> The pathname specified may be relative, although it cannot extend outside the current servlet context. **If the path begins with a "/" it is interpreted as relative to the current context root.** This method returns `null` if the servlet container cannot return a `RequestDispatcher`.
>
> ...